# OAuth2 Auth Code with PKCE Without Whitelisting Reply/Redirect URLS Ok?

Tags: oauth-2.0, pkce

We have a home grown identity provider.  It has supposedly implemented Auth Code Flow with PKCE but when you register clients it doesn't ask if the client is a public/private client and additionally it doesn't whitelist redirect/reply urls with client app registrations.

I'm trying to explain to my security team why this is a big deal and should be rectified, but I'm not seeing where the [PKCE RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) explicitly states that you must whitelist redirect/reply urls for public clients.

Today the IDP's auth endpoint will send auth codes in a redirection to any url you provide it in the original auth request.  Isn't this opening us up to man in the middle attacks, or am I mistaken and making a big deal of nothing, somehow PKCE patches this exploit?

Comment: was my answer helpful or did you find some better reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public clients have no way of proving their identity - that the application is really the client it is supposed to be. So an attacker can use their `client_id` and create a phishing application. If the OAuth2 server doesn't validate `redirect_uri`, the phishing application will easily get an auth code and exchange it for tokens.

The [OAuth2 RFC says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.6):

> The authorization server
> MUST require public clients and SHOULD require confidential clients
> to register their redirection URIs.

You can also check the "OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations":

- [redirect URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-3.5)
- [Validate Pre-Registered "redirect_uri"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.2.3.5)
- [Issue a "client_id" Only in Combination with "redirect_uri"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-5.2.3.3)